Trying to replace a for loop with pool to write data to a xlsx file with multiple processes
I have a program that reads a csv file with Pandas and then writes the data to an xlsx file with XLSXWriter in order to make plots of the data.  I am trying to change the for loop which is used to write the data into xlsx with a pool in order to use multiple processes to speed the data transfer up (working with big csv files).
This is the portion of the original program used to write the data to the xlsx file.
 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_file_path, {"nan_inf_to_errors": True, "strings_to_numbers": True})
 data_worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 Data_chart = workbook.add_worksheet("Charts")
    
 for column_num, column_name in enumerate(data):
     data_worksheet.write(0,column_num,column_name)
     data_worksheet.write_column(1, column_num, data[column_name])

Now I am trying to switch that to a pool and have only been able to come up with the following which errors.
### The first 4 lines of code are there only to get the number of columns in the csv file.  
   with open(path1, 'r') as csv1:
        first_line = csv1.readline()
    ncol = first_line.count(';') + 1 
    print("number of columns is: " + str(ncol))


### The 3 workbook lines of code below are the same as before.
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_file_path, {"nan_inf_to_errors": True, "strings_to_numbers": True})
    data_worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    Data_chart = workbook.add_worksheet("Charts")
    
### at this point I made a function to be able to map the pool to.
    ncol1 = range(ncol) 
    def data_transfer():
        for column_num, column_name in enumerate(data):
            data_worksheet.write(0,column_num,column_name)
            data_worksheet.write_column(1, column_num, data[column_name])

    if __name__ == '__main__':    

        with Pool(processes=4) as pool:

            pool_transfer = pool.map(data_transfer, ncol1)
                    
            pool.close
            pool.join

This could be way out in left field, I am new to switching things to work on multi cores not sure how to go about this.

You may get a speed up from processing the CSV files in parallel but you are unlikely to get any speed-up from XlsxWriter by writing data to the worksheets in parallel. This is because the bottlenecks aren't in the user facing parts you can parallelize but rather in the back end where the data is written to xml files and those xml files are zipped into an xlsx file.

^^^ To your point I did run a speed test before on each of the steps to see where things are slow and yes you are correct ~60% of the time is on writing to the file and ~40% of the time is in processing the CSV file to XLSX (where my question is to speed this up using multiprocessing).  I realize I am going after the smaller bottleneck although a small gain would be welcomed and learning how to mutliprocess this data transfer would be beneficial as well.

What you need to check is whether 60% of the time is being spent in the part that is being parallelized. From experience it probably isn’t. Most of time in an XlsxWriter program is spent in close() which can’t be parallelized (by the user). But you should check with your own profiling, I may be wrong.

That wasn't worded well.  60% of the time is spent on "close".  40% of the time is spent on writing data to the xlsx file (the thing I am trying to multiprocess).
